# Spree: uninitialized constant Spree::ThemeSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

It seems like many of the Spree's extension don't support latest version of Spree (1.2.0). I tried to install few gems but I keep getting

```
uninitialized constant Spree::ThemeSupport
```

I read solution somewhere which is "It was deprecated, and is now removed you should be defining Deface overrides in the app/overrides directory now". But how to exactly do that? Has anyone implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably solved it by now, but if not, here's a example of 1 i changed from ThemeSupport to Deface

https://github.com/geermc4/spree_user_groups/blob/ec2a169d96acf6cbcf731d24d518134e55598d29/app/overrides/add_user_groups_to_configuration_menu.rb

Commented in the bottom is the ThemeSupport